# MacOS High Sierra : Xcode failed to download Use the purchase page Error during installing Xcode 9.3

Tags: macos-high-sierra, mac-app-store, xcode9.3

Yesterday I update **MacOS Sierra** to **MacOS High Sierra** than I remove **xCode 9.2** after that when I try to install **xCode 9.3** from App Store, It gives me below error:

> **Xcode failed to download, Use the purchase page to try again**

I tried below solutions.

**1.** Remove Account and again add it.

**2.** https://gist.github.com/ferbass/3ecc06a8ae992365bf73

**3** https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/61646/xcode-failed-to-download-use-the-purchases-page-to-try-again **(But There's no Debug menu in MacOS High Sierra)**

**4** Try to install xCode with Different account but facing same error.

**5** Other Applications are downloadable but facing error only in xCode installation.

**below is screenshots**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have any anti-virus installed?

Comment: no any antivirus installed in my Mac.

Comment: Btw, I am not sure it is the more suitable forum for such question. I think that specialists about that kind of issue are hidding at http://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: @KeyMaker00, thanks for link, I have also raise this question in stack exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

From [How to fix / Reset App Store app on Mac OSX - El Capitan:](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/245406/how-to-fix-reset-app-store-app-on-mac-osx-el-capitan)

**Delete:**

```
~/Library/Caches/com.apple.appstore
~/Library/Caches/storeaccount
~/Library/Caches/storeassets
~/Library/Caches/storedownload
~/Library/Caches/storeinappd
```

I didn't have some of those folders, but I did have a couple of extras that looked fishy, so I deleted them too:

```
~/Library/Caches/storeassetd
~/Library/Caches/storedownloadd
```

Run `sudo softwareupdate --clear-catalog` in Terminal

From http://osxdaily.com/2016/10/08/mac-app-store-temp-cache-folder/ (paraphrasing):

**1.** Quit out of the Mac App Store

**2.** Open Terminal and run `open $TMPDIR../C/com.apple.appstore/`

**3.** Hit Return and the `com.apple.appstore` folder will open in the Finder of Mac OS

**4.** Delete the contents of this folder

And finally:

**5.** Navigate to `~/Applications` in Finder and move Xcode to the Trash [Note: This step was necessary for me, but ymmv]

**6.** Reboot

**7.** Launch App Store. Search for Xcode. Install it fresh.

Answer (score 0):

From the [official forum](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7530546) :

> Firewalls, anti-viral software and apps such as Little Snitch are know
>   to interfere with the Mac App Store.

Furthermore I would suggest to :

1. Restart your computer, try again
2. Clear the Apple Store Cache, try again
3. Clear the DNS setting if it's not default, try again